# In an elseif statement, how do I stop the next one from being run

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am new to programming and PHP, and am quite discouraged by my inability to get this code to work.

```
$query_uid2 = mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE uid2 IS NOT NULL");
$query_uid3 = mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE uid3 IS NOT NULL");

//the update queries

$q2 = mysqli_query($db_conx,"UPDATE table SET uid2='$var' WHERE uid1='$uid1'");
$q3 = mysqli_query($db_conx,"UPDATE table SET uid3='$var' WHERE uid1='$uid1'");

//I used mysqli_num_rows function to create 2 more variables for next step...

if ($q2_num > 0 && $q2 == TRUE) {
    echo "success";
    die();
} elseif ($q3_num > 0 && $q3 == TRUE) {
    echo "success";
    die();
}
```

My problem is that both if statements carry out, despite the fact that the `query_uid` is in fact **not** `null`.
I am trying to stop the second statement from running if the first statement conditional is true, is this possible?
I hope you can understand my question.  I've been trying to figure this out for 2 weeks now, starting to feel hopeless.  I can't find anything online or in my book explaining what I'm trying to do.

To explain it again, I don't want the second conditional to run, only the first one assuming it's `true`. Can someone give me a hint as to how this is possible?  I've tried all I can.

Comment: Don't you still understand that you have all your queries run already, *before* any conditions? And therefore these conditions has not a slightest effect on the queries?

Comment: if you want some query to be run based on some condition, you have to put this query execution inside this condition. not above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first `if` is `true`, then what's in the `elseif` will not run. But when you assign the queries' results to those variables, they run before your conditions. The solution is simple, just run the queries inside the condition.

```
if (condition) {
    mysqli_query(...);
}
```

Specifically for your situation:

```
if ($q2_num > 0) {
    mysqli_query($db_conx,"UPDATE table SET uid2='$var' WHERE uid1='$uid1'");
    echo "success";
    die();
} elseif ($q3_num > 0) {
    mysqli_query($db_conx,"UPDATE table SET uid3='$var' WHERE uid1='$uid1'")
    echo "success";
    die();
}
```